# Knockout observables not being updated from within an event handler

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-textext

I have a very simple code. I am using the textext jQuery plugin.

```
    $('#'+field).textext({ plugins: 'tags' }).bind('isTagAllowed', function(e, data){
    window.kmodel.enableButtons(false);
    window.kmodel.showError(false); 
    //make AJAX calls while stuff is disabled
    //re-enable
```

}

The problem is that the UI doesn't get updated until after the handler has exited, at which point it's already too late.

I guess I could use jQuery itself, but I find knockout much more elegant, and I really want to get to the bottom of this. Maybe knockout has a function like pushChanges or something?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ku2cj/1/

So here's the thing. If you leave the alert, the UI updates as expected. But if it's removed, the UI doesn't update.

Comment: Changing observables should update the UI immediately, the fact that you're doing it inside an event handler shouldn't matter. Can you share some more code or try and reproduce the problem with a site like http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Just looked at the fiddle, not quite sure what your problem is.  The button and test is updated in the DOM before your alert box shows, and again after the ajax method finishes.  The UI updates immediately after each observable is modified

Comment: I know. What I said was that if you remove the alert, the UI never updates. The AJAX call takes some time, and there's a visible pause, but the UI doesn't update during that pause. I just put an alert there to show which point I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I have a version of this working for you that is using promises. I don't know anything about the texttext jQuery plugin, or how it might be interacting with KO in terms of DOM manipulation. That being said, what I have works but it may not be the solution you want.

Like you said, if you take out the `alert` from your original fiddle then the DOM is not correctly updated. You don't see the "adding" text - only the "error" text after the code inside the binding handler finished executing. But if you introduce promises into the equation, then you ensure that everything is happening in it's proper order. I used Q.js here because that's what I'm used to, but there are other libraries to use (or just use [jQuery's $deffered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/))

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77vya/). I added a method to your KO model called `enable` which sets the `true`/`false` values on the observables in your model. Here is the updated textext section

```
$('#textarea').textext({
    plugins: 'tags'
}).bind('isTagAllowed', function (e, data) {
    window.komodel.enable(false) // happens first
   .then(function () {
        $.ajax({  // only after first happens, ajax starts
            url: "/Ku2cj",
            async: false,
            timeout: 2000
        }).success(function () {
            window.komodel.enable(true); // after ajax is complete, this happens
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Well that solved my problem and I learned about promises too!

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the browser is still executing the code, and since you set `async` to false, it's executing all the code synchronous and therefor doesn't have time to update the UI.

What if you change the following:

```
window.komodel.enableButtons(false);
window.komodel.showError(false);
window.komodel.showAdding(true);

  $.ajax({
      url: "/Ku2cj",
      async: false,
      timeout: 2000
  });

window.komodel.enableButtons(true);
window.komodel.showAdding(false);
window.komodel.showError(true);
```

With an asynchronous construction:

```
window.komodel.enableButtons(false);
window.komodel.showError(false);
window.komodel.showAdding(true);

$.ajax({
    url: "/Ku2cj",
    timeout: 2000
}).then(function() {
    window.komodel.enableButtons(true);
    window.komodel.showAdding(false);
    window.komodel.showError(true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kVLaK/

Comment: This works but it won't work because the call must by sync so that the event handler is paused and proceeds based on what is returned from the server.